# how to get a natural int as a new number after a decimal point in Ocaml using float_of_int?

Tags: floating-point, integer, ocaml

**What do I want?**

I want to conver a integer like `5` to `0.5` and `12345` to `0.12345`

**What did I try?**

```
let rec getDecFrac c = if c < 1.0 then ((float_of_int c) /. (float_of_int 1)) else getDecFrac ((float_of_int c)/. (float_of_int 10));;
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int
```

**What am I doing worng?**

Comment: You're mixing `float`s and `int`s a bit arbitrarily. I would suggest to implement it as `float -> float` initially, then wrap it in a function which converts the initial `int` to a `float`.

Comment: Also, dividing by `1` is rather pointless, `float_of_int 1 = 1.0`, and while you haven't specified what you want it to do with negative numbers, I have a feeling that it currently doesn't do what you intend.

Comment: I don't care about negative numbers. how can I declare about ```float -> float```

Comment: remove all uses of `float_of_int` and use `float` literals instead of `int` literals.

Comment: if you mean by this```let rec getDecFrac c = if c < 1.0 then c /. 1 else getDecFrac c/. 10;;``` I get the same error

Comment: `1` and `10` are `int` literals. The equivalent `float` literals would be `1.0` and `10.0`. Also, again, dividing by 1 is pointless. `x/1 = x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main pearl of functional programming is about splitting a complex task into a set of smaller tasks. We can see that mathematically  `1234` and `0.1234` are connected as `1234 / 10^4` or more generally as `x / 10^d(x)` where `d(x)` is the number of decimal digits in `x`. Indeed, moving the decimal point by one position is the same as dividing by ten.

So let's encode it. How would we write the `number_of_digits` function? We can go dirty and convert the number to string and count the letters. But, indeed, it feels dirty. Let's write a simple recursive alorithm that counts how many divisions by ten a number can sustain,

```
let rec number_of_digits x = 
  if x < 10 then 1 else 1 + number_of_digits (x/10)
```

Looks pretty simple, but don't forget to test your implementation,

```
# number_of_digits 1;;
- : int = 1
# number_of_digits 1234;;
- : int = 4
```

Looks good. Obviously it won't work with negative numbers, but it is easy to fix it (left as an exercise),

```
# number_of_digits (-1234);;
- : int = 1
```

Now we can write our function, exactly as our mathematical specification,

```
let to_frac x = 
  float x /. 10. ** float (number_of_digits x)
```

and test that it works,

```
# to_frac 1234;;
- : float = 0.1234
# to_frac 0;;
- : float = 0.
# to_frac 1;;
- : float = 0.1
```

## Advanced Topics

Of course, anyone who knows that floating-points in OCaml (and in many other languages, including C/C++) are represented using the base 2 not 10, will exclaim that this function doesn't work. Well indeed, we can see that not all decimal numbers are representable using base-2 floating-point numbers. And even our simple `1234` is not really returning `0.1234` but the closest representation of that number in binary floats,

```
# printf "%.60f" (to_frac 1234);;
0.123399999999999995803356966916908277198672294616699218750000- : unit = ()
```

So be aware of that fact and especially of the fact that if a number looks like `0.1234` it maybe not really the `0.1234` but just an approximation of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're starting from a string that's missing the leading `0.`, you can just prepend `"0."` and then use the built-in `float_of_string` function to do the parsing:

```
let decimals_of_string s =
  float_of_string ("0." ^ s)
```

```
utop # decimals_of_string "123";;
- : float = 0.123
utop # decimals_of_string "42";;
- : float = 0.42
```